# Converting bytes from a for loop to strings in python

Tags: python, pyqt

am having a QTableView and trying to get all values in the column. Am able to retrieve the values using the code below

```
data= []
for row in range(model.rowCount()):
    data.append([])
    for column in range(model.columnCount()):
        index = model.index(row, 0)
        data[row].append(str(model.data(index)))
for item in data:
    names = '{}'.format(item[0])
    print(names)
```

The problem am facing is that am getting the values as bytes for example

```
b'Austria'
b'Belgium'
b'Denmark'
b'England'
b'Finland'
```

instead of

```
Austria
Belgium
Denmark
England
Finland
```

Comment: change `names = '{}'.format(item[0])` to `names = '{}'.format(item[0].decode())`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert bytes to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string)

Comment: It's not a duplicate because i tried it and got the same error as am getting from using the code you've provided. The error is `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Comment: it's a duplicate, have you tried the answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working code to solve your problem

```
names = []
data = []
for row in range(model.rowCount()):
    name = model.data(model.index(row, 0))
    data.append((name))
    names.append(name)
for name in names:
    decoded_name = bytes(name).decode()
    print(decoded_name)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @And3r50n 1. That solved my problem